# atomically replace content of SQLite database, preferably in SQL or python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a python script that supports an `--edit-the-database` option to invoke the user's preferred editor on a dump of the script's SQLite database. This option is intended to facilitate quick access to parts of the database that the script's other options don't provide access to, particularly during the development of this script.

Once the script has dumped the database's content, launched the editor and verified that the modified content is still valid then it needs to replace the existing database content.

First it removes all existing content by executing this SQL (using python's sqlite module):

```sql
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
DELETE FROM sqlite_master WHERE type IN ('table', 'index', 'trigger');
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
VACUUM;
```

and then it loads the new content using the sqlite module's `executescript()` method:

```python
cursor.executescript(sql_slurped_from_user_modified_dump)
```

The problem is that these two operations (deleting existing content, loading new content) are not executed atomically: press `CTRL-C` at the wrong moment and the database content has been lost.

If I try to execute those two blocks of code inside a transaction then I get the error:

```
Error: cannot VACUUM from within a transaction
```

And if I keep the transaction but remove the `VACUUM` then I get the error:

```
Error: table first_table already exists
```

I have an ugly workaround in place: prior to calling the editor, the script copies the dump file to a safe location, writes a warning message to the user:

```
WARNING: if anything goes wrong then a backup of the database 
    can be found in /some/path
```

and, if the script continues and completes loading the new content, then it deletes the copy of the dump. But this is pretty ugly!

I *could* use `DROP TABLE` instead of the `DELETE FROM sqlite_master ...`, but if I am trying to allow the database to be modified in this way then I am allowing that the list of tables itself may change. I.e. if the user adds this to the dump:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t3 (n INT);
```

then a hard-coded list of `DROP`s like this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DROP TABLE t1;
DROP TABLE t2;
DROP INDEX ...
...
cursor.executescript(sql_slurped_from_user_modified_dump)
...
END TRANSACTION;
```

isn't going to work second time round (because it doesn't delete table t3).

I could use filesystem-atomic operations (i.e. something like: load the modified dump into a *new* database file; hardlink new file to old file), but that would require the script to close its database connection and reopen it afterwards, which, for reasons beyond the scope of this question, I would prefer not to do.

Does anybody have any better ideas for *atomically* replacing the entire content of a database whose list of tables is not predictable?

Answer (score 0):

*In case Google leads you here ...*

I managed to do the first half of the task (delete existing content inside a single transaction) with something like this pseudocode:

```
-- Make the order in which tables are dropped irrelevant. Unfortunately, this
-- cannot be done just around the table dropping because it doesn't work inside
-- transactions.
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

indexes =  (SELECT name 
            FROM sqlite_master 
            WHERE type = 'index' AND 
                  name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_autoindex_%';)
triggers = (SELECT name 
            FROM sqlite_master 
            WHERE type = 'trigger';)
tables =   (SELECT name 
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE type = 'table';)

for thing in indexes+triggers+tables:
    DROP thing;
```

At which point I thought the second half (loading new content *in the same transaction*) would just be this:

```
cursor.executescript(sql_slurped_from_user_modified_dump)

END TRANSACTION;
-- Reinstate foreign key constraints.
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

Unfortunately, pressing CTRL-C in the middle of the two blocks resulted in any empty database. The cause? [cursor.executescript() does an *immediate* `COMMIT` *before* running the provided SQL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript). That turns the above code into *two* transactions!

This isn't the first time I've been caught out by this module's hidden transaction
management, but this time I was motivated to try the [apsw](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/) module instead. This switch was remarkably easy. The latter half of the code now looks like this:

```
cursor.execute(sql_slurped_from_user_modified_dump)

END TRANSACTION;
-- Reinstate foreign key constraints.
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;
```

and it works perfectly!